# List of time stamps not sorting properly

Tags: sorting, elixir, phoenix-framework

[image: Sorted list of time stamps]

I have a list of maps each with a key stating the "inserted_at" time in which the items were inserted in my database. I want to sort this list in descending order to show the most recent items first. I thought I had it but when looking closer for some reason the 2nd and 3rd elements should be swapped as well as the 5th and 6 elements.

Any idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because you are comparing `NaiveDateTime` in Elixir.

You should use [compare method](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/NaiveDateTime.html#compare/2) instead of `==, >, <`.

e.g, `Enum.sort(z, &(NaiveDateTime.compare(&1, &2)==:gt ))`.

Comment: One other suggestion would be to store all times in UTC because some of the most annoying bugs in the world involve working with multiple time zones. You can still do the same kind of comparison Yonghao suggested, using the `DateTime` module.

Answer (score 1):

According to the release notes for [Elixir v10](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/releases/tag/v1.10.0) below this issue should be fixed natively.

Elixir v1.10 streamlines the sorting functions by introducing both :asc and :desc shortcuts:

```
iex> Enum.sort(["banana", "apple", "pineapple"], :asc)
["apple", "banana", "pineapple"]
iex> Enum.sort(["banana", "apple", "pineapple"], :desc)
["pineapple", "banana", "apple"]
```

As well as adding the possibility to pass a module to perform semantic comparisons. For example, to sort dates, one now only needs to pass the Date module or even {:desc, Date} for descending semantical sort:

```
iex> Enum.sort([~D[2019-12-31], ~D[2020-01-01]], Date)
[~D[2019-12-31], ~D[2020-01-01]]
iex> Enum.sort([~D[2019-12-31], ~D[2020-01-01]], {:desc, Date})
[~D[2020-01-01], ~D[2019-12-31]]
```

These API improvements make the code more concise and readable and they have also been added to Enum.sort_by, Enum.min_by, Enum.max_by, and friends.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize (since [Elixir v1.10](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/releases/tag/v1.10.0)):

#### Sort by inserted_at (date and time):

```
... |> Enum.sort_by(& &1.inserted_at, NaiveDateTime)
```

```
... |> Enum.sort_by(& &1.inserted_at, {:desc, NaiveDateTime})
```

#### Sort by inserted_at (date):

```
... |> Enum.sort_by(& &1.inserted_at, Date)
```

```
... |> Enum.sort_by(& &1.inserted_at, {:desc, Date})
```

Answer (score -3):

By default a 'map' doesn't provide a 'sorting order'.  Not sure what I'm looking at or what language this is in.  In Java you would use this type of collection:  http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/sortedmap.html

Comment: It's in Elixir.